# CSS stylesheet not responding working with chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, stylesheet, caret

I recently started my first program (very basic) and I ran into an issue immediately!

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gweeble.css" />`

Using the code above, I attempted to attach a css stylesheet.  In order to make sure it wasn't just me, I copy pasted the code from an example.  And to make sure that the CSS was right, I put it in a style tag in the head of my HTML file... it worked.  Next, I entered the dev tools in chrome (the browser I'm using.  This is on a Chromebook using the caret editor)  and the css file wasn't even there!!!  If you have any ideas, I really need help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gweeble.css" />
      <title>gweeble</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="uhhhh">
        <meta name="keywords" content="google, grooble, gweeble, bored, I'm bored, Im bored, ugh, uhhh">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

</body>
```

```
body {
    background-color: #4542f4; }
```

Comment: If you are using Chrome to view your page, you can press F12 to open Developer tools. Open the console and refresh your page. Also check the Network tab. There should be something in those that will give you a clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: It may be a case sensitive name "Gweeble.css" and won't load with "gweeble.css".

Comment: I’ve looked in dev tools and refreshed.  I don’t think that it’s case sensitive, but even if it is, it follows the same pattern as to capital letters... sorry I don’t know how to explain that better

Comment: So what color is `gweeble.css` on the Network tab of dev tools? Is it red or black.

Comment: all the answers so far are good but please try clearing your Browser Data in chrome then while developing use the <style> tags in <head> then after wards create a css file and transfer you styles there.

Comment: all the answers so far are good but please try clearing your Browser Data in chrome then while developing use the <style> tags in <head> then after wards create a css file and transfer you styles there.

Comment: I have done that, and no luck.... it did work while in the head!  But when transferred over to the css file, it didn’t work.  Chrome for some reason doesn’t even put it on dev tools, and I don’t know how to open the file manually.  I tried adding a folder to workspace, but that only works for downloads...

Answer (score 1):

ANOTHER SOLUTION!!!!
Here's another reason why browsers may fail to load your css file....

I've read all the responses here (and on several other sites) but was still failing to have my apparently valid css file loading into my browser (as confirmed using the inspector - right-click over code in Chrome and look at 'sources' tab).

I usually use Chrome but also tried Edge with same results - html5 code ran fine but the layout was not being rendered. Inspection showed that css file was never loaded, never mind executed.

My issue turned out to be that the html code had been copied from on-screen tutorials and pasted into Notepad ++.  In the process, I ended up with the wrong speech (") marks, so my guess is that the 'meta charset="utf-8"' statement
was inconsistent with the type of speechmark in the code?

Bottom line is that changing all the speechmarks by simply deleting and then re-typing resulted in a physically different shape of speechmark and working code.

Hope this was helpful....

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because of a bad link in the `<link>` element. Are your HTML and CSS files at the same level in the file structure?  If you need to go back up a level you may need to do `href="./gweeble.css"` Also try doing a hard refresh of your browser (hold the shift key down and click the refresh button if you're using Chrome) to clear the cache. Oh and double check the spelling of the CSS file name to ensure it is a correct match.

Comment: The spelling is right, I already cleared the the cache, the files are in the same folder... I've tried all there is... I'm new to stockflow, so I don't know how to put my code in... so I

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gweeble.css" />
      <title>gweeble</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="uhhhh">
        <meta name="keywords" content="google, grooble, gweeble, bored, I'm bored, Im bored, ugh, uhhh">
        <meta name="author" content="Daniel Reiffer?">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
      
    </body>
  </html>

Comment: @noobiecoder Put your markup into your question, not as a comment to someone else's answer.

Comment: Finally got it... had to get a text editor on iPhone then send it through google drive and a bunch of other stuff... sorry for the random metadata descriptions and stuff...

Comment: Also I've just dumped your code into html and css files in a folder and it worked. Which means it must be file structure or naming issue. Have you called your html file `index.html`

Comment: Does the first have to be called index.html?  Ibe been using SoloLearn and it said it just has to have .htm or .html at the end.... but I’ll try it...

Comment: I named it index.html, and now all that displayed in the browser is the code!! Chrome auto put my html in a pre style tag.  An now both of the files user “type” are listed as plain text!

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you are viewing the correct HTML file? You can also check the page source (CTRL + U) to check the markup in your document.

Comment: I am positive that I am viewing the correct file.  I opened dev tools in the browser to check... the html shows up, css doesn’t.  Did you try it?  I don’t know if it’s just my browser/computer or the code itself...

Comment: This `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gweeble.css" />` doesn't show up in the markup when viewing dev tools you mean? That's strange if **you are** indeed viewing the **correct** HTML file with such line of code.

Comment: The html link tag shows up, but the css has no affect and the css file will not show up in dev tools.

Comment: Try opening (go the link of) the `gweeble.css` once you view the page source on dev tools. Then see what you can find there.

Comment: Do CTRL + U or Inspect Element (Chrome), then all assets and links appear underlined

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  My computer was set to auto put my files into a google drive section ☹️.  The problem was fixed by simply moving the folder to downloads.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using node.js, express, and EJS as templating engines

I just found this error on my website and looked here. 
The problem I faced is
if you have a CSS file in your public directory i.e. views(in my case)

Note: You can access your CSS file from Browser Dev tools.
Using Chrome, go to Network in dev. section, and then click on CSS file. And check headers.

Make sure when you link any CSS file without any error of

- type : "text/css"
- Correct href = ""

Now, if you still can't access it, 
so the problem may be that your browser may not be accessing the file correctly. Check the path where it should be, and where you had placed.

In my case: *localhost:3000/views/css/style.css* throws an error

But The actual link should be: *localhost:3000/css/style.css* worked

So change the href accordingly, and remove extra folders coming between so that your browser can access it directly.